# ¿Cómo establecer atributo src con ubicación física de archivo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web

Necesito establecer el src de una imagen  y no logro ubicar el archivo dentro del servidor.

Explico:
Las carpetas de mi proyecto están asi dentro de mi proyecto de nombre CMSProject:

```
CMSProject  

     -Areas

     -Bin

     -Content

     -Controllers

     -Models

     -Views
```

El archivo desde donde quiero setear el atributo src esta en un subdirectorio (Shared) de la carpeta Areas:

```
 -Areas
    
    -Admin
       
        -Views

            -Shared

               DowloadReport.cshtml
```

El archivo que nesecito encontrar esta en  un subdirectorio (Images) de la carpeta Content:

```
 - Content

        -Images

               loading.gif
```

Yo escribi algo asi, pero me dice que no encuentra el archivo...

¿Como puedo hacer para resolver este problema?

```
 function checkReport(reportTitle) {
    if (growl == null || growl == undefined) {
        growl = $.iGrowl({
        type: 'simple',
            delay: 0,
            title: reportTitle,
            small: false,
            message: 'Su reporte se está generando. Una vez finalizado será descargado en su navegador.',
            placement: {
                x: 'right',
                y: 'bottom'
            },
            animShow: 'fadeInUp',
            animHide: 'fadeOutDown',
            icon: 'vicons-support',
            image: {
                src:"../Content/loading.gif"
            }
        });

        $(".igrowl-dismiss").html("X");
    }
    IsGenerated();
    checkingReport = setInterval(IsGenerated, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Tryby .. y ¿como seria eso ?

Comment: ...y además debe ser accesible al servidor web. Si la imagen está fuera del ámbito del servidor web no hay forma de que puedas llegar a ella

Comment: Gracias luisfer ..Agradeceria que fueras un poco mas explicito en tu respuesta ..algo de codigo seria buenisimo

Answer (score 1):

La ruta de la imagen debe ser relativa a la URL que estás viendo en el navegador y tú la estás poniendo con base en la ubicación de la vista. Creo que lo mejor sería crear una variable en Javascript con la ruta absoluta del sitio y usarla para asignar la imagen.

De preferencia en la plantilla del proyecto, dentro de `<head> ... </head>`, y antes de cualquier script que requiera acceso a la ruta coloca:

```
<script>
// Puedes usar el dominio completo o solo /
// Si el proyecto está dentro de una carpeta, no olvides agregarla:
// Por ejemplo: https://www.midominio.com/ruta-del-proyecto/
const CMSProjectUrl = 'https://www.midominio.com/';
</script>
```

Luego, en tu función:

```
function checkReport(reportTitle) {
    if (growl == null || growl == undefined) {
        growl = $.iGrowl({
        type: 'simple',
            delay: 0,
            title: reportTitle,
            small: false,
            message: 'Su reporte se está generando. Una vez finalizado será descargado en su navegador.',
            placement: {
                x: 'right',
                y: 'bottom'
            },
            animShow: 'fadeInUp',
            animHide: 'fadeOutDown',
            icon: 'vicons-support',
            image: {
                // Agregas la ruta absoluta del sitio
                src: CMSProjectUrl + 'Content/loading.gif'
            }
        });

        $(".igrowl-dismiss").html("X");
    }
    IsGenerated();
    checkingReport = setInterval(IsGenerated, 10000);
}
```

Esto te servirá también para ejecutar scripts por AJAX:

```
$.ajax(CMSProjectUrl + 'carpeta/scripts/archivo.ext');
```

Answer (score 1):

Si `checkReport` se encuentra dentro de la vista que se renderiza desde el servidor (*DowloadReport.cshtml*) se puede aprovechar el sistema de plantillas y el renderizado del servidor para que determine la ruta relativa del archivo con **Url.Content** de la siguiente manera.

```
function checkReport{
    ...
    image: {
        src: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")',    // Basado en la estructura de directorio que se presenta en la pregunta.
    },
    ...
}
```