# editar datos en una ventana modal usando jquery ajax , mvc y pjp

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]cordial saludo

buenos dias soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion estoy diseñado un sistema para un colegio pero al momento de usar una ventana modal con jquery me carga los datos pero cuando edito solo me sale error del servidor o no muestra el error en la consola anexo imagenes, si me pueden ayudar
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSOHR.png)

```
[![introducir el código aquí][2]][2]
```

como se puede ver tenemos el archivo addcalificaciones.js que es donde esta la función actualizardatos , el controlador donde estoy enviando los datos por POST , al igual que el error de la aplicacion no me muestra nada en consola[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código modelo calificaciones updatecalificaciones

```
public function UpdateCalificaciones($Id,$Nota1,$Nota2,$Nota3,$NotaFinal)
    {
        $statement=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE calificaciones SET nota1=:nota1,nota2=:nota2,nota3=:nota3,notafinal=:notafinal WHERE idCalificaciones=:id");
        $statement->bindParam(':id',$Id);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota1',$Nota1);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota2',$Nota2);
        $statement->bindParam(':nota3',$Nota3);
        $statement->bindParam(':notafinal',$NotaFinal);
        if($statement->execute()){
            header('Location:../Pages/index.php');
        }else{
            header('Location:../Pages/edit.php');
        }
    }
      }
```

controlador

```
<?php
require_once('../Model/Calificaciones.php');
if($_POST) {    $modelocalificaciones = new Calificaciones();
    $id=$_POST['idcalificacion'];
    $Nota1=$_POST['nota1'];
    $Nota2=$_POST['nota2'];
    $Nota3=$_POST['nota3'];
    $Notafinal=$_POST['notafinal'];
    $modelocalificaciones->UpdateCalificaciones($id,$Nota1,$Nota2,$Nota3,$Notafinal);
} else {
    header('Location:../Pages/index.php');
}
?>
```

codigo javascript

```
function actualizardatos() { id=$('#idcalificacion').val(); nota1=$('#nota1').val(); nota2=$('#nota2').val(); nota3=$('#nota3').val(); notafinal=$('#notafinal').val(); cadena ="id=" + idcalificacion + "&nota1=" + nota1 + "&nota2="+ nota2 + "&nota3="+nota3 + "&notafinal="+ notafinal; //"&asignatura="+asignatura+ //"&documento="+documento+ //"&docente="+docente+ //"&nombre="+nombre+ //"&grupo="+grupo+

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../Controller/edit.php",
    data:cadena,
    success:function(r){
        if(r==1){
            swal.fire({
                icon:'success',
                title:'Se ha Modificado el Registro',
                showConfirmButton:false,
                timer:1500
            })
        }else{
            swal.fire({
                icon:'error',
                title:'Error del Servidor',
                
            })
        }
    } });

}
```

Comment: Tienes que publicar el código; una foto del código no sirve.

Comment: ¿`edit.php` es solamente la función `UpdateCalificaciones`?

Comment: si exacto desde java envio a la pagina de controlador edit.php en donde  el controlador llama a la funcion UpdateCalificaciones pero me sale un error como se puede ver en la imagen del servidor pero no me muestra el error

Comment: @eduardomanjarres Entonces, en el `IF` tendrias que colocar `echo '1';` en caso que la condición se cumpla y cualquier otra cosa en caso que no suceda. No es necesaria una redirección ya que AJAX es asíncrono. Saludos.

Comment: ¿El script _edit.php_ está dentro de _/web/colegio/Calificaciones/Controller_? Si no, entonces el error es de ruta _../Controller/edit.php_, de ser el caso, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371998/c%c3%b3mo-establecer-atributo-src-con-ubicaci%c3%b3n-f%c3%adsica-de-archivo/372007#372007)

Comment: verifque la ruta esta bien dentro calificaciones esta el carpeta Pages donde esta la carpeta JS y contiene addCalificaciones lo que hago es ../Controller/edit.php

Comment: En el navegador, revisa la pestaña _Network_, ahí tienes más detalles de lo que está pasando.